# Setting variables through temp table in vertica

Tags: sql, database, vertica

I know setting variables in Vertica takes too long so I thought of creating a temp table and selecting necessary values. This is in case I want to change the timestamp in multiple places without doing it manually or searching for it. However, performance is noticeably worsened when using this temp table method. My question is why is it so and is there a better workaround?

I have this code:

```
DROP TABLE DAY_RANGE;

CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE DAY_RANGE
(   
    start_ TIMESTAMP,
    finish_   TIMESTAMP
)

INSERT INTO DAY_RANGE(start_, finish_)
SELECT '2016-09-09 00:00:00', '2016-09-10 00:55:55'

select count(*) from clickcache.click cc
where AMP_CLICK_DAY between (select start_ from DAY_RANGE) and (select finish_ from DAY_RANGE)

select start_ from DAY_RANGE
```

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure I understand what you mean by "setting variables in Vertica takes too long"?  Could you include an example of this because I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: I am actually not sure how to do it. I saw an example and it was very complicated. If you have a way to do it, please share. Thank you!

Comment: There isn't a way to set a session variable in Vertica for that purpose, which is why I'm a little confused. There are `vsql` client-side variables, though. See my answer for more details. If you want to point me in the direction of the examples you saw, I can help interpret it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `cross join` instead. I'm not sure, but it might help.

Another idea is to unsegment your local temp:

```
CREATE LOCAL TEMP TABLE DAY_RANGE
(   
    start_ TIMESTAMP,
    finish_   TIMESTAMP
) UNSEGMENTED ALL NODES;
```

Also, if you are using `vsql` you can create variables there, as well using `\set`. If you aren't using `vsql` many clients will detect the `:parameter` variables and prompt appropriately.

```
\set start_time '''2016-09-09 00:00:00'''::timestamp
\set end_time '''2016-09-10 00:55:55'''::timestamp

select count(*) 
from clickcache.click
where AMP_CLICK_DAY between :start_time and :end_time
```

Also, if you are wondering what the deal is with the `'''` in the set statements... this acts more like a template. The `'` needs to be in the end result. In order to do that, you have to escape it. So the first `'` is treated like a string, the next `''` are escaped versions of `'`. (Hope that makes some sense). In the end, there will be only one `'` after it is processed.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with vsql but I just ended up using  :start_time and :end_time and indicating the values there which is exactly what I wanted! Thank you!

Comment: Glad it helped. :-)  vsql has this ability, but so do many other clients. Some clients will prompt you for variables whenever it encounters one in that form (`:parameter`).

Comment: I would and tried, but my reputation is below 15. I will definitely accept it once I am at 15. Thank you very much!